# Changing team in Xcode and transfer app to company account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect

I've developed an app for a company using my private Apple Developer account.

Now, the app is ready to be published to the App Store, and the company enrolled in the Developer Program and added me as a developer.

Now, how can I transfer the app, including all the certificates and everything (the app includes push notifications) to the company's account?

Also, I've heard that I should change the `Team` in Xcode to the new account's, but I get these errors:

[image: Errors]

Does anybody know how can I transfer the app as smooth as possible (including using TestFlight) to the company's account (that I've been added as a developer to it with my private account)?

Thank you!!